# Why is GetByID a command rather than a query?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Please see the following articles: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS and http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/04/20/types-of-cqrs/.  Here is some code:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public void Save(Customer customer) { /* … */ }
    public Customer GetById(int id) { /* … */ }
    public IReadOnlyList<CustomerDto> Search(string name) { /* … */ }
}
```

They both describe GetByID as commands i.e. in both cases domain objects (Customer) are returned by the methods instead of DTO objects (CustomerDTO).  Why is this? GetByID returns data from the database.  It should be a query i.e. return CustomerDTO, shouldn't it?

**Update 25/09/17**

Say I retrieve a Product from the database.  I then want to run some methods on the Product (which change instance variables) and then persist the changes back to the database.  Would I do this:

```
ProductDTO productDTO = ProductRepository.GetProduct(1);
DomainProduct domainProduct = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DomainProduct>(DomainProduct);
domainProduct.RunSomeMethod();
```

or this:

```
DomainProduct domainProduct = ProductRepository.GetProduct(1);
domainProduct.RunSomeMethod();
```

The first fragment of code prevents hits on the write database, (I thought CQRS was suppose to prevent read hits on the write database)? However, GetByID also hits the write database.

Which fragment supports CQRS? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But your title is not correct.`GetById` is not a command in neither of the articles (it could not be a `command` anyway, maybe a command handler or command method). It is however **used** on the command side.

**After update:**

This is correct:

```
DomainProduct domainProduct = ProductRepository.GetProduct(1);
domainProduct.RunSomeMethod();
```

> The first fragment of code prevents hits on the write database, (I
>   thought CQRS was suppose to prevent read hits on the write database)?
>   However, GetByID also hits the write database.

It prevents writes on the read model and reads on the write model.
However, you can load a write model (an Aggregate root) from the write persistence in order to send commands to it - this is the purpose of `GetProduct(id)`.

In your case, `DomainProduct` should not have any query method (i.e. getters), only command methods (i.e. `activate()`). This is how you prevent reads on the write model: by not having any query method. CQRS is CQS applied to any method on all models. This restriction applies **only** to domain entities; any other object (i.e. the repository) can have query method on the write side (like `GetProduct(id)`).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think they're drawing the distinction between a query that returns read-only data, that will never be used once it's reached the UI, and a Customer domain object, that is (probably) being fetched for the purposes of supporting an edit so has some 'higher' purpose.

In some instances, where your read store is eventually consistent, you would want to fetch a single Customer object from your main-store which is the record of truth, whereas you would be running your queries against your read store which may not have caught up with all the published changes.

Answer (score 1):

From the first article:

> **Command side**
>
> Since the read side has been separated the domain is only focused on
>   processing of commands. Now the domain objects no longer need to
>   expose the internal state. **Repositories** have only a few query methods
>   aside from **GetById**.

It doesn't tell you that GetById is a command. But rather that GetById is a method (for retrieving your aggregate on which you can apply your command) on repository, which is a part of command stack. But it has nothing to do with queries from query stack. And that's all. I haven't read it all, but I believe that conception is the same for both articles.

Comment: It is in the CommandRepository.  Does that not make it a command?

Comment: No. It's here for retrieving your aggregate from "write side" , on which you will apply your command.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have to have a read repository and write repository within the same bounded context to be using CQRS?

Comment: As both act on different models Aggregates vs. DTOs. They should be separated. And in the end write and query side could be considered as different bounded contexts. They both are working on some overlapping data, but they are differently modeled.

Answer (score 1):

In general (and CQS):

- Commands return nothing and have side effects.
- Queries return something useful, have no side effects and are idempotent.

This is how commands are different from queries. I do not see why you call the `GetByID` method as a command.

In terms of CQRS, queries are indeed meant to return data from the read model. However, queries are not wrapped in repositories. `GetById` method in the repository is required to fetch the domain object on the write-side. Then, it is manipulated by the command handler and changes are persisted on the write-side.

These operations have nothing to do with query/read side of CQRS.

Comment: I am calling it a command because the method query/reads data rather than writes (command) data.  Is that not correct?

Comment: I described what command and query mean in CQS. CQRS is a more "distributed" version of it. But it does not change the essence of terminology. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference to side effects.  +1.  Could you have a look at my uodated posr?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is GetByID a command rather than a query?

It *is* a query.

> They both describe GetByID as commands i.e. in both cases domain objects (Customer) are returned by the methods instead of DTO objects (CustomerDTO). Why is this? GetByID returns data from the database. It should be a query i.e. return CustomerDTO, shouldn't it?

The *shape* of the data returned does not change the fact that the method is a query.

Query is typically understood as expressed by Bertrand Meyer in describing [Command Query Separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)

> Queries: Return a result and do not change the observable state of the system (are free of side effects).

In this case, the result happens to be a domain object rather than a DTO, but it is still a query in Meyer's sense of the word.

CQRS takes the same understanding of command and query, and divides the responsibilities.  Use cases that don't change the observable state of the system are handled by the "read model", and use cases that try to modify the observable state of the system by the "write model".

If we were to pseudo code this split, the result would look exactly as you would expect

```
namespace ReadModel {
    public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public IReadOnlyList<CustomerDto> Search(string name) { /* … */ }
    }
}
```

And we *could* repeat this approach in the write model...

```
namespace WriteModel {
    public class CustomerRespository {
        public CustomerDto GetById(int id) { /* … */ }
        public void Save(CustomerDto customer) { /* … */ }
    }
}
```

... but we usually don't.  [CQRS](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/08/13/command-query-separation/) evolved from [Distributed Domain Driven Design](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/category/dddd/), which as you might guess was heavily influenced by [tag:domain driven design].  DDD is strongly influenced by the object oriented style; the responsibility for modifying the state of the model should reside within the domain model ([Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)).

Therefore, in the write model, we don't return state from the respository, but instead a reference to a domain model entity that updates its own state in response to a command

```
namespace WriteModel {
    public class CustomerRespository {
        public Customer GetById(int id) { /* … */ }
        public void Save(Customer customer) { /* … */ }
    }
}
```

The core logic of the application is unchanged

- Read old state from the book of record
- Use the old state to compute a new state
- Replace the old state with the new state in the book of record

the distinction is just in the organization of the code.

```
DomainProduct domainProduct = ProductRepository.GetProduct(1);
domainProduct.RunSomeMethod();
```

This is the style that you would normally see in CQRS, because it is what you would normally see in Domain Driven Design: the application code doesn't know anything about how the underlying data is managed -- it only talks to the interfaces supported by the domain model (the Repository and the Product).  Evans worked with a tiered architecture - the application layer talks to the domain layer, and the domain layer talks to the database.

> I thought CQRS was suppose to prevent read hits on the write database

The key idea in CQRS is that the objects that you use when reading are not the ones you use when writing.

```
// I'm in a write use case
Product product = productRepository.getProduct(1);
product.changeTheProductState(...);

// I'm in a read use case
ProductView view = productRepository.getView(1);
return view.queryCurrentState();
```

If all I want to do is ask questions about the product state, then I fetch from the repository an object that is connected to the *read* database, and ask away.  If reads are 10x more frequent than writes, that alone is going to prevent a lot of hits to the write database.

But writes are still connected to the *write* database (that's where the writes are durably stored, after all), and the repository may need to refresh its local copy of the state before it starts calculating what it is going to write.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to DTO.  +1.  Could you have a look at my updated post?

Comment: I think the edited post moved to a different concern. For the question whether you need to persist the aggregate or map persisted state to it, I would say - neither. I prefer making aggregates as static state machines and keep aggregate state separate, so I don't need to map it and keep persistence concerns separate from business concerns. Also, for the first example code, I don't like having `Search` in aggregate repositories. Querying is for the read side of CQRS and `Search` is definitely a query.

Comment: @Alexey Zimarev, GetByID reads from the database, however it is contained in the write repository.  What is the different concern you refer to?